# Customize bash looks for user profile on debian 9

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, bashrc, bash-profile

I am trying to customize the bash prompt on Linux Debian 9.

I got the script from Github and I modified the file .bashrc

On the terminal, when I log in as root, I can see the customization I was looking for, but once I exit to the normal user, all the customization vanishes and I go back to the old looking of Debian's terminal.

On the /root folder I have 2 relevant files .bashrc and .profile

The .profile file is configured to import the configuration from the .bashrc file by default, so I did not change anything in there.

The /root/.profile file configuraton:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n || true
```

So the question is: how can I make my user bash customization the same as my root (su) bash customization?

Screenshots included:

When I first launch my terminal:

[image]

When I log in as root:

[image]

When I exit root:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user has their own `.bashrc` and `.profile` configuration file on Debian.

So, you could enter your customized prompt also in `/home/sparrow/.bashrc`.

Alternatively, you can move your changes from `/root/.bashrc` to `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which would then work for both users `root` and `sparrow` (in fact for all users on your system).